# What hook can I use to modify custom post data before it is displayed on the page?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, posts, hooks, actions

I need to check if a certain value is true in the post_meta right after the wp fetches a custom post from database, If it's false I need to modify/add some data to the post and then display the modified version, if it's true it should continue as usual. What would be the best hook and approach in general to accomplish something like this?

Edit: Forgot to mention before, but I would HIGHLY prefer to do this inside a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter to modify content before it's output.

```
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {
    // maybe limit to archive or single cpt display?
    if( is_post_type_archive( 'your-cpt' )
        || is_singular( 'your-cpt' ) ){
        global $post;
        $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'some-key', true );
        if( false === $meta ){
            return $content . 'some extra content';
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
```

Comment: This would work, but what if I need to modify the meta along with content?

Comment: add a filter to [`get_post_metadata`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L269).

Answer (score 0):

I would do this inside of my `single-custon_post_type.php`, using the `get_meta()` function and conditional checks.

If the meta field is not set, or does not contain data you need - you can then display content in a separate way.